# RAML Max length of an item in a String array

Tags: mule, raml, raml-1.0

I am defining a RAML spec. I have an attribute to hold an array of string. I want to make a rule that a string value in the array can have only maximum 3 charactors only (For example: `regions: ["wes","nrh"]` is valid. `regions: ["lenghthyvalue", "anotherLenghthyvalue"]`  invalid). How can I handle it in RAML. My current code is as following:

```
regions:  
     type: string []
     required: true
```

Available attributes are maxItems only. How to limit the character length of an item ?

I use raml 1.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First create a string type that has `maxLength` and `minLength` attributes. Then you can reference that type in your array type instead of just a string array. Example:

```
#%RAML 1.0
title: test
version: 1.0
types:
  region:
    type: string
    minLength: 3
    maxLength: 3
  regions:  
     type: region []
     required: true

/test:
  get:
    queryParameters:
      regions: region
```